# Java mail: sending email without SMTP

Tags: java, email

I want to send an email without using SMTP protocol. Is that possible to implement using Java? Since, my remote machine does not have access to google, yahoo and other accounts. and even my office mail can not be configured using SMTP server due to some security issues. Is any other way to send an email from remote machine.

Comment: So how do you send email from your desk?

Comment: How do you expect to send email without a mail server?

Comment: @Here: He didn't say no email server, he just said no SMTP server. The likes of Exchange and Notes don't have to use SMTP.

Comment: email is mail sent with SMTP - the likes of exchange/lotus notes etc, are not email, but other forms of messaging.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaMail section at java.sun.com lists many [third party products that plugin to the JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html). Hopefully one of those will fit your needs but I can't be more specific because you don't say what non-SMTP sending options you have open to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup Your own SMTP server on remote machine, IMHO, it is better than incorporate it into program directly.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to send an email without using
>   SMTP protocol. Is that possible to
>   implement using Java?

1. With Java you can implement any Layer-5 network protocol.
2. ALL mail servers using SMTP to receive messages. At any time you have to connect with SMTP to the destination mail server.

If you cannot get out from local network to the Internet with some services you will need a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) or network [tunnel](http://www.ohardt.com/mailbridge/) to connect the destination.